# CakePHP ACL - How to get Group-only permissions?

Tags: cakephp, acl, cakephp-1.3

I just want group only permissions - I don't need user based permissions. The cake 1.3 manual (http://book.cakephp.org/view/1646/x11-2-4-1-Group-only-ACL) says:

> In case we want simplified per-group
>   only permissions, we need to implement
>   bindNode() in User model.

```
function bindNode($user) {
    return array('Group' => array('id' => $user['User']['group_id']));
}
```

> This method will tell ACL to skip
>   checking User Aro's and to check only
>   Group Aro's.

However when I add groups and users via the baked controllers I still end up with an AROs table with nested groups/users for user-based permissions. I expected the AROs table to look like this (because the manual says this is what it will look like):

```
+----+-----------+-------+-------------+-------+------+------+
| id | parent_id | model | foreign_key | alias | lft  | rght |
+----+-----------+-------+-------------+-------+------+------+
|  1 |      NULL | Group |           1 | NULL  |    1 |    2 |
|  2 |      NULL | Group |           2 | NULL  |    3 |    4 |
|  3 |      NULL | Group |           3 | NULL  |    5 |    6 |
+----+-----------+-------+-------------+-------+------+------+
```

But instead is looks like this:

```
+----+-----------+-------+-------------+-------+------+------+
| id | parent_id | model | foreign_key | alias | lft  | rght |
+----+-----------+-------+-------------+-------+------+------+
|  1 |      NULL | Group |           1 | NULL  |    1 |    4 |
|  2 |      NULL | Group |           2 | NULL  |    5 |    8 |
|  3 |      NULL | Group |           3 | NULL  |    9 |   12 |
|  4 |         1 | User  |           1 | NULL  |    2 |    3 |
|  5 |         2 | User  |           2 | NULL  |    6 |    7 |
|  6 |         3 | User  |           3 | NULL  |   10 |   11 |
+----+-----------+-------+-------------+-------+------+------+
```

Here is my user model:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'User';

    var $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester'));

    var $hasMany = array(
        'Post' => array(
            'className' => 'Post',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        )
    );
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Group' => array(
            'className' => 'Group',
            'foreignKey' => 'group_id'
        )
    );

    /**
     *
     * In case we want simplified per-group only permissions
     * see http://book.cakephp.org/view/1547/Acts-As-a-Requester
     * @param unknown_type $user
     */
    function bindNode($user) {
        return array('Group' => array('id' => $user['User']['group_id']));
    }

    function parentNode() {
        if (!$this->id && empty($this->data)) {
            return null;
        }
        if (isset($this->data['User']['group_id'])) {
        $groupId = $this->data['User']['group_id'];
        } else {
            $groupId = $this->field('group_id');
        }
        if (!$groupId) {
        return null;
        } else {
            return array('Group' => array('id' => $groupId));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well. I assume you have an Groups model/table as well, which also contains

```
var $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester'));
```

This is the reason why your ARO table contains both instances. Bind let's you change the the node of the ARO tree to which a particular model is assigned. The solution described in the documentation means that if you check your model using `ACL->check()` it then uses the newly bound ARO node.

You are also assigning the group id in the parent node for the `User` model, which is you ARO tree is constructed the way it is. I assume that in order to realize your solution just remove the `acts_as` and `parent_node` declaration in your user model.

To check for permissions you then can simply use your `User` model.

Hope that this clears up things a bit. I just started getting into `ACL` so, i might have misunderstood something in the `bind` behaviour. You can see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you still contain the old information on the database.

If you empty all the tables, including the aros, acos and aros_acos, and add create the groups and the users again you will obtain the documented output.

Answer (score -1):

I have never used that method, but the concept of a group without any users seems meaningless. Cake uses the user and group information to decide who belongs to which group so that it can apply the appropriate group permissions.

Looking at 'the Book', though, your users *must* have a group_id set:

> "Every user has to have assigned
>   group_id for this to work."

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    group_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    created DATETIME,
    modified DATETIME
);
```

In my applications, which don't use `bindNode`, I set the permissions only by group and it works fine.

Comment: Yes, "every user has to have assigned group_id for this to work" - so why does the book show the resulting AROs table with ONLY groups in it?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that. This is an option that I wasn't aware of and it may be that the book is correct but your implementation isn't. My reading of it is that use of bindNode modifies the logic rather than the model so, therefore, your implementation is correct and the book is wrong. It's good, but anyone can edit it. I noticed the other day that some of the Containable section has vanished. Or maybe it was never there!

Comment: The more I use CakePHP the more I like it, but often got to work very hard with the documentation :)